Différences entre "hydrophobe" et "hydrofuge"
La définition de hydrophobe est, dans le Robert:

Que l'eau ne mouille pas (opposé à hydrophile).

et hydrofuge:

Qui préserve de l'eau, de l'humidité.

Je n'arrive pas a faire la distinction.

-phobe = "peur", -fuge = "éviter, fuir"?

L'huile est hydrophobe (elle ne peut pas se mélanger à l'eau), la cire est hydrophobe (l'eau ne peut pas traverser), etc... On applique un produit hydrofuge à une surface pour rendre cette surface imperméable. Ce produit peut être de la cire par exemple, ça dépend du support...

-phobe s'oppose à -phile: l'un a une affinité, pas l'autre.

Hydrophobe: qui "n'aime pas" l'eau (ne se mélange pas avec elle), s'oppose à hydrophile: qui "aime" l'eau (l'attire, l'absorbe). Se dit surtout du coton.
Hydrofuge: qui fait fuir l'eau, s'oppose à hydrophore (rare): qui attire l'eau, qui la charrie.
Etymologiquement parlant, il n'y a pas une grosse différence mais dans l'usage, hydrofuge s'est spécialisé pour qualifier les produits tiers protégeant de l'eau alors qu'hydrophobe désigne une propriété intrinsèque d'une matière.

C'est bien ce que je disais, mais tu le dis mieux, et avec plus de détails :-) +1
